# Help me with this sentence

Tags: grammar

And this is how to get pregnant is

this is how is to get pregnant(I don't think so)

or

And this is what to get pregnant is like

Do they have the same meaning?

Comment: The first two sentences in your post are not grammatical. Therefore it is basically impossible to answer your question, since we do not know what you are asking.

Comment: @CarSmack: I don't find, for example, *"That's just how it is"* ungrammatical. How is OP's *first* version syntactically/grammatically any different? The second OP himself identifies as unacceptable. The third is also fine (assuming we all accept "to get pregnant" as a valid alternative to "getting pregnant" here).

Comment: @Gabriel: What is "this"? Is it an account of *what the experience off getting pregnant is like* (a "description")? Or is it a "prescription" consisting of *advice on how to successfully conceive*? Without that information, the question is "Unclear".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I get *That's just how it is.* So I guess the syntax matches. Still I would say OPs #1 is not idiomatic, at least to some. I don't think just any noun phrase (especially with infinitive?) can be substituted for *it* in the construction *And this is how it is* and the sentence be idiomatic. Thanks for pointing out the workable example.

Comment: @CarSmack: Yeah - well I did say ***assuming*** we accept an infinitive as the target of "how" here. Mostly we'd use a gerund today (we do really want an ***NP*** there), but gerunds were relatively uncommon a century or two ago. Offhand I don't know whether or how Victorians would have referenced a *verb* form in such constructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"And this is how to get pregnant is" - this almost sounds like you are trying to say

> And, this is how to get pregnant.

which may not be appropriate for polite or unknown company. :)

However, for this first sentence, it sounds like you were really trying to say

> This is how it is to get pregnant,

which is OK, but the focus here is on the act of getting pregnant which may not be what you are trying to say.

Your second sentence, it sounds like you are trying to say

> This is what getting pregnant is like.

which is better, if you are focusing on the experience or fact of pregnancy itself.

Comment: Yeah, this sentence should really be avoided in a formal setting, "And, this is how to get pregnant." It almost sounds as if it will be followed with a physical demonstration.

Comment: Consider changing your verb from _to get_ to _to be_ to focus on the pregnancy part rather than the precipitating event.  _This is what **being** pregnant is like._

Comment: For some reason it seems more natural to me to say "This is what it's like to be pregnant."